# How to set layoutToLeft or toRight in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am newbie to flutter, how to set the image search to layoutToRight of image menu? having difficulty at this part now

[image]

My code is as below:

```
  return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
  home:Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45.0),
      child: AppBar(
        leading: Container(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){/* open left menu */},
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_menu.png")),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){/* open search */},
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_search.png"),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0),
          )
        ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use title attribute, to achieve desire output.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45.0),
    child: AppBar(
      leading: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {/* open left menu */},
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_menu.png")),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      titleSpacing: 0.0, // added update
      title: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {/* open search */},
          child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_search.png"),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Sir, how do I setMarginToLeft ? The search image is quite far to the menu image? Sorry for bothering as I am android developer which sudden switch to flutter

Comment: use titleSpacing=0.0. @LiewSyetChau also available in update.